# In heaven, will everyone be equally special to us (Catholic)?

Tags: catholicism, heaven, relationships

It is believed that in heaven, we will have deep and intimate relationships with its every member.

In heaven, will the level of spiritual connection and intimacy shared between everyone be equal ? That is, in heaven, will the level of spiritual connection and intimacy that I share with Sam will be exactly the same as the level of connection and intimacy that I share with Jane?

Or in heaven, will the connection and intimacy between certain members be more stronger than between some other members? For instance, it can be thought that if you were married in your earthly life, the connection and intimacy that is present between you and your earthly spouse will be stronger than that of what you share with other members in heaven; or if you had a very close friend in your earthly life, it seems possible that in heaven, you will have a deeper relationship with that particular friend, compared to your other heavenly relationship.

I am asking this question purely out of my interest in Theology.
Please answer according to Catholic understanding.

Thank you,

Comment: It seems implicit in practice of seeking of the intercessions of the Virgin Mary that there are indeed those closer to Christ in the Kingdom. Mary is the closest to Christ (the last that was made first), and therefore has a special place.

It calls to mind the saying of St. John of Kronstadt (a saint to Eastern Orthodox christians, but no Roman Catholic): "In hell there is a democracy and in Heaven there is a kingdom". All beings are equal in Hell, but in Heaven there are orders of angels and beings.

Comment: Hello, I don't think my question is duplicate because the other question is asking whether or not we will have intimate relationship with every member in heaven, but my question is whether or not those intimate relationships are equal in its strength and its level.

Comment: @Ian This is what has been passed down to you: _Christ himself_ is the last that was made first- also the first made last.  "Now that he ascended, what is it but that he also descended first into the lower parts of the earth? He that descended is the same also that ascended up far above all heavens, that he might fill all things." Would you believe it if you heard it from his own mouth? He said, "Fear not; **I am the first and the last**: I am he that liveth, and was dead; and, behold, I am alive for evermore, Amen; and have the keys of hell and of death."

Comment: @Andrew, What you said is true, but doesn't contradict what I wrote. I know in Orthodox tradition when Christ says John the Baptist is the greatest in the kingdom, "Yet the one who is least in the kingdom of heaven is greater than he", that is thought to refer to Mary and I assume this is also in line with Catholic teaching. We should not think that just because a phrase or attribute applies to Christ that it does not also apply to those in the church as well. Christ says all who are last will be first, and try to keep the comment on topic of the discussion of Catholic tradition.